# Multi store email template in magento

Tags: php, email, magento

I have two stores in my Magento Site (English/Welsh). Is there a way of sending emails in different language depending on what store view they purchased it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do that

- copy your mails to a app/locale/your_locale and localize them there
- in the backend, under `System -> Transactional Emails` create new, translated mail templates. Next you have to assign these special mail templates under `System -> Configuration -> Customer`, `System -> Configuration -> Sales Emails` and so on for your store view.

Comment: Thank you mate, the sales email for different store view worked like a charm. It was so simple as well. Great help!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to copy "email" directory from app/locale/en_US/template/ to the other language directory like this app/locale/xx_xx/template/email then open the files within this directory and translate it.